# Mariadb-server 10.2. fresh install in debian 8 shows error

Tags: debian, mariadb, debian-jessie

I have followed the link for installation .

> https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=23Media&distro=Debian&distro_release=jessie--jessie&version=10.2

After adding Repo.list and keys , it started installing .But ended up with the following error message

*Unable to set password for the MariaDB "root" user
An error occurred while setting the password for the MariaDB administrative user. This may have happened because the account already has a password, or because of a communication problem with the MariaDB server. You should check the account's password after the package installation.*

But Mariadb-10.0 , 10.1 distributions are installing properly and working fine .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution given by this link works for me 
https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14416

It was a bug with ext3 file system. They fixed it already . The patch will be released in version 10.2.11.But for this above situation please do the following steps [I am doing fresh installation. so no databases inside].

> 1. open my.cnf file , find **innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT**
>      comment it and save .
> 2. rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/*
> 3. mysql_install_db
> 4. systemctl start mariadb.service
> 5. mysql -u root [without password]

After entering console , you can set password using the following command

> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('pass');

Answer (score 0):

Try to access MariaDb in CLI without a password.

```
mysql -u root
```

If you can do that, you can then just set a password for a user.

Comment: its not installed .so obviously i cant do that

Comment: Check this link: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253023/unable-to-set-password-for-the-mysql-root-user)

Comment: Even better: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806738/mariadb-10-1-and-ubuntu-16-04-unable-to-set-password-for-the-mariadb-root-use)

Comment: for you information ,  it doesnot contain any pre installed databases. Its fresh  machine .i tried reloading os and installed mariadb . stilll the same .so your answer  won't help me .

Comment: did you run `apt-get -f install` after installation? Maybe is a package problem. This command repairs all dependencies. Or you can consider upgrading to Debian 9 with just a couple commands. Debian 9 have MariaDb by default in repository.